# subscript / superscript for c# charting control; injecting text formatting

Tags: c#, .net, charts, text-formatting

I use the charting control from the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` library. it works great, but it has one very big disadvantage: the labels can't be formatted, so subscript or superscripted letters are not possible.

are there any methods, how a text formatting could be injected?
i have considered yet the following possibilities:

- replacing sub/sup characters by superscripted characters. here is a list of these characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts 
  Problem: not all characters are available, not all fonts support all unicode features, and some characters are not exactly resized large ones
- overwriting the `PrePaint` / `PostPaint` events. problem: these events are not fired for label / title paint events
- injecting a `DrawString` hook - is that possible?
- something I have not considered yet?

Comment: im sorry . . . i can't help but notice u have 2.4k points and yet you still have not fully registered yet . . .

Comment: ps i'm also interested in the answer as well